# A 810nm led has a 350mW/sr rating. How do you convert to mW/cm2?

Tags: led

This led:
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/vishay-semiconductor-opto-division/VSMY98145DS/7041914

Has a 350mW/sr rating.

- How do I convert this to irradiance in mW/cm2?
- Can you achieve a lower irradiance by lessening the input amperage or voltage?

Comment: You need to define the distance and the cone angle (90 deg) relative to a steradian angle then compute the spherical surface pr accept the flat Cartesian area with errors.  Current may be safely reduced to 10% of rated Amp.

Comment: Thank you everyone. Also got some feedback on another forum, linking here for completeness of reference https://cr4.globalspec.com/thread/138096/If-a-single-810nm-led-will-produce-a-irradiance-of-13-mW-cm2-how-many-milliamp-is-that-led-likely-to-be-approximately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

350 mW/sr means \$(4\pi)(350\ {\rm mW})\$ into the complete sphere around the source (if the source were to be emitting equally in all directions, which of course it isn't).

So at a distance \$r\$ from the source, the peak irradiance is \$\frac{(4\pi)350\ {\rm mW}}{(4\pi)r^2}=\frac{350\ {\rm mW}}{r^2}\$.

As shown in figure 4 of the datasheet, you can indeed reduce the output irradiance by reducing the drive current:

[image]

Comment: The cone angle is at 50% power of 90 deg. Which is smaller than the surface area of a sphere/4. Does one double the power for Center area flux? ,mW/sqcm

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75, the datasheet is giving, and we're calculating, the peak irradiance (irradiance in an infinitesimally small region at the center of the output beam). For average irradiance onto a surface of any size, you'd need to average over the portion of the beam profile that the surface intersects. The beam profile is also given in the datasheet.

Comment: Yes so in this question , may we assume centre then double intensity/sqcm

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75, I don't get your point. You could submit your own answer to make it clear.